# These two pgp public keys are the same but different?

Tags: pgp, tor, kleopatra

I'm doing some research on .onion websites and was trying to verify an onion URL.

I got a public key from two different sources: side by side they are identical until about ten lines before the end. Which suggests to me that they're different.

But when I tried importing them both into Kleopatra it treated the second as if it was identical to the first (whichever order I did it) - basically saying you've already imported that public key. Fingerprint was identical and so was the "valid from" date. (Is this why Kleopatra treats them as identical?)
Neither key will verify a signed message from the website even though the website provided the one key basically alongside the signed message, which is really confusing me - if it was a copycat website surely they'd make sure the (fake) pgp and signed message they provided would match?

So.. I'm really confused. Am I doing something wrong? Can you tamper with public keys? I don't understand how they would have the same fingerprint but be different - does the fingerprint mean nothing then?

Excuse the ignorance. I am trying to learn about PGP encryption but it's a work in progress.

Here are the two public keys:

```
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
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=eX+0
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```

```
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
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=RBxW
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```

Comment: It is impossible to analyze PGP keys from pictures. Please format them as text, instead. That said, they could have different signatures or something. Use `gpg --list-packets` instead of `diff` that is not aware of the ASCII armored PGP format.

Comment: The included public key is likely the same as reported. The latter part where the difference is about user id, subkeys, attributes ... associated with the key. See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880.html#section-12.1

Comment: Actually both _keys_ (and keyids/fingerprints) and the userid are the same (@SteffenUllrich); it is (only) the signature dates and value on the subkey that differ. In the first block, the masterkey signature is dated 2023-01-19 but the subkey signature is dated 2020-11-19 and expired 2022-12-31; in the second block the masterkey signature is the same but the subkey signature is dated 2023-03-12 with no expiration. Looks like someone created the key cluster in 2020 and tried to extend it in 2023 but on the first try mistakenly re-signed only the masterkey.

Comment: What does that mean in terms of verifying them? I'll add the signed message onto the original post as well and see if you can verify them because it isn't working for me